# hide keyboard on touch of scroll view

Tags: ios, background, uiscrollview, keyboard, hide

I have developed my app, after which, I discovered I need to add a Scroll view and embed all elements in it. 
After doing so, I noticed that the keyboard doesn't disappear on touch outside of the keyboard. 
I know because the IBAction is tied to the ViewController and not the scroller.
the scroller can't have any IBAction though. 
Is there  way you can help with this? 
I have searched a lot and kinda lost in hiding the keyboard simply after adding the Scroll view. This one shouldn't be that complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add UITapGestureRecognizer on your UIView insted of UIScrollView

Comment: check ma answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785395/dismissing-the-keyboard-from-a-uitextfield-uitextview-as-a-subview-of-uiscrollvi/14788474#14788474

Comment: @Rajneesh071 that solved the issue
Thanks a million!!!!

Comment: then make +1 for ma answer...:)

Answer (score 19):

Cleanest way in iOS 7:

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

Swift version:

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

Comment: Try also `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag`

Comment: You also could set that modes in Storyboard

Answer (score 6):

Please try this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *yourTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollTap:)];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:yourTap];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Then in

```
- (void)scrollTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {

    //make keyboard disappear , you can use resignFirstResponder too, it depends.
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

*** remarkable you said you had to embed all elements in to scrollview right?, that means you have added something like `UIButton` as a subview to scrollview and then when you init `UIButton` you should add action too, so in scrollTap just [self.view endEditting:YES] is enough cuz if you press at some point in `UIScrollView` and if that point is `UIButton`, it will activate action of `UIButton` cuz it stays in the most upper layer as you add it as a subview and if that point is not a button so scrollTap will be activated. Sorry I didn't look to it carefully but it should be like I said.

Comment: The logic for testing whether the button should be touched should be placed in `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`.  If it returns NO, the button can accept the touch.  This way you don't need all the logic for every button in the tap gesture method.

Comment: I tried inserting those lines in my .m file and it says "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'"

Comment: Could you please explain your answer more? Is there a framework I need to include?

Comment: no, it's just scrollview delegate, you don't have to include framework, now I amtry to understanding why it raise  "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'" because for mine, it's work, I will do my best

Comment: @AaronBrager , thanks for point out let me be the option then.

Comment: "Use of undeclared identifier self" likely indicates that your instance method definition is wrong.  It should look like `- (void)doSomething {`.  Perhaps you are missing the parenthesis, or you used a + instead of a -?

Answer (score 2):

Based off of @piam's answer here is the swift version for those who would like a quick copy-paste:

```
//put this where you initialize your scroll view
var theTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "scrollViewTapped:")
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(theTap)
```

.

```
//This can go anywhere in your class
func scrollViewTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    scrollView.endEditing(true)
}
```

side note:

make sure you have your textfields set up like this:

```
exampleTextField.delegate = self
```

and at the top of your class add `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can registered a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the baseViewControlls view and then deal with the gesture

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(yourScrollView.yourTextField.isFirstResponder)
    {
        [yourScrollView.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Or when your keyboard is show , you can add a transparent mask button over the baseView , which is between the keyboard and the yourView , and the button while receive the sender like this :

```
- (void)maskButton:(id)sender
{
    [_maskButton removeFromSuperView];
    if(yourScrollView.yourTextField.isFirstResponder)
    {
        [yourScrollView.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check isFirstResponder.  You can just call `[yourScrollView.yourTextField resignFirstResponder];` - it will do nothing if yourTextField is not the first responder.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes you are right , but I think my code is a little more efficient . In this case it maybe very very little , but maybe in another cases , it maybe more efficient , such as code in the scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: It's probably less efficient, because `resignFirstResponder` probably checks anyway.  But you're correct that it's not a big deal either way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this answer. I'm pretty new to iOS development. Can you explain more what I should do?

Comment: Joe: the "first responder" is the object that has the highest priority for user input.  If it accepts keyboard input, iOS automatically shows the keyboard.  When a text view (or any text-accepting object) resigns being the first responder, iOS hides the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss immediately on touch, rather than on tap:

Add a PanGestureRecognizer:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:nil action:nil];
panGR.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
panGR.delegate = self;
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:panGR];
```

Implement the gesture delegate:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    
    if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) [self.view endEditing:YES];
    
    return NO;
}
```