# Hide UITableview when touches on screen except that table view

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

am having a scroll view with many text fields when we start editing text field displays tableview below.

when we touches anywhere on screen have to hide table view and that is fine and we touch on tableview cell the text in that cell is displayed in textfield

My problem is when i touches on Uitableviewcell not getting the data in uitextfield .

help me please...

my code is

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismisstable)];
    tapGesture1.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;    
    [testScroll addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];
    [tapGesture1 release];




-(void)dismisstable
{

self.autocompletetableview.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: have you implemented didselectRow ..?

Comment: yes i  implemented all delegate methods of UITableView

Comment: make NSLog in didselectRow, and let me know output?

Comment: yes while selecting cell nslog works gud.but i cant hide the tableview when i touches any where on screen

Comment: now make NSLog in -(void)dismisstable

Comment: sorry ,for this code although am selecting tableview cell am unable to call did select row

Comment: wt is size of ur tableView ???

Comment: if(autocompleteTableView)
            [autocompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];
      
        autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,180) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
   autocompleteTableView.rowHeight=22;
             
        [viewForautoCompleteTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(88,389 ,200,autocompleteTableView.frame.size.height)];

Comment: @iPatel  can u help me

Answer (score 0):

First just check tableView datasource and delegate

```
yourTableView.delegate=self;
yourTableView.dataSource=self;
```

**AND**

Just add `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
    [scr addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}


- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //Get touch point
    //CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scr];

    //Hide tableView
    [self.yourTableView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Follow my answer for more [dismissing the keyboard from a UITextField,UITextView as a subview of UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785395/dismissing-the-keyboard-from-a-uitextfield-uitextview-as-a-subview-of-uiscrollvi/14788474#comment20707823_14788474)

Comment: it is fine but when i touches tableview cell have to show that text on textfield but it is not working by this code .using this didselectRow is not at all calling

Comment: i have given a static table view can u tell me how?

Comment: i have given those .if it is selected on tableview have to call did select row and all delegates else (other than table view if we touch)have to hide tableview